# how to create horizontal listview builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

hi I have Row in flutter and I want add some widget on row with listview.builder, listview sort all item vertically. but I want show them horizontally. in the image below you can see my code and the result.so how can i change the listview.builder to horizontal?
[image]

Comment: could you add your code instead of screen shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set `height` for your ListView if you want to use it horizontally, and set `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal`:

```
Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left)),
          Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
            height: 10,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  height: 10,
                  width: 10,
                  color: Colors.red,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 10,
            ),
          )),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_right)),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in listview scrollDirection you need to set for horizontal scrolling

```
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget horizontalList = new Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
  height: 200.0,
  child: new ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.red,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.orange,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.pink,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.yellow,),
  ],
)
);
);
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
      child: horizontalList,
  ), 
);
```

Comment: thx but your code is static and only set for container. But my Container is different each time